# WebGL Combined Camera Rotations

Tags: matrix, rotation, webgl

Why is it that when I multiply a rotation matrix with the camera matrix -

```
let rotation = m.mult4(m.rotateX(xRads)),m.rotateY(yRads)));
camera = m.mult4(rotation,camera);
```

I get incorrect rotation. But when I multiply that same rotation matrix with just the *translation* portion of the camera matrix I get the correct rotation?

```
let rotation = m.mult4(m.rotateX(xRads)),m.rotateY(yRads)));
camera = m.mult4(rotation, m.identity([ camera[12], camera[13], camera[14] ]))
```

Is there some kind of unintended accumulation that's throwing out the result? Is there a way to successfully multiply with the entire camera matrix so I don't have to track rotations separately?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing two different things here: rotate a (presumably) already rotated coordinate system vs. setting the translation component on a newly created rotation matrix.

> Is there some kind of unintended accumulation that's throwing out the result?

Unintended by you, yes. Unintended by linear algebra, no.

> Is there a way to successfully multiply with the entire camera matrix so I don't have to track rotations separately?

Not really, as even if you were to decompose the matrix you'd have the problem that there's more than one valid result.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's quite right. Both matrices are doing rotations and translations it's just the first has an implied translation which comes from the camera. I think the problem is that the rotation components of the matrices are taken from angles that are relative to an axis - not an arbitrary point - which means they don't compose as intended. I think I'd need to use something like trig identities instead to get the right result.